# Spring REST ambigious method

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I need a spring rest controller for inserting data. This is what i already got:

```
@RestController
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractRESTController<E extends Identifiable<P>, P extends Serializable> {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void create(@RequestBody final E entity) {
        service.create(entity);
    }
}
```

So i am able to insert a entity at http://mycontext/
What i need now is a method which accepts a list of entitys at the **same path**. Basiclly this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void createAll(@RequestBody final List<E> entities) {
    for (E entity : entities) {
        service.create(entity);
    }
}
```

So how can i make spring aware of that im sending a array and not a single entity and then use the other function?
My error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'sfusersRESTController' bean method 
public void AbstractRESTController.createAll(java.util.List<E>)
to {[/sfusers],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'sfusersRESTController' bean method
public void AbstractRESTController.create(E) mapped.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to map more than one request to a given path, you will have to use different HTTP methods; eg. POST, PUT.

In your situation, I would make the URLs different; i.e. one /mycontext/as-entity and /mycontext/as-list.

Or you MUST have the same URL - it must be able to handle all kinds of request bodies. So you could have one RequestMapping() which expects an Object - and then handle that Object - either as an Entity or a List.

Personally, I would still prefer different RequestMapping paths.

Answer (score 1):

define different request mapping paths so that it can make corresponding callback using

```
@RequestMapping(value = "")
```

Now your rest controller will look like this:

```
@RestController
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractRESTController<E extends Identifiable<P>, P extends Serializable> {

    @RequestMapping(value = "create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void create(@RequestBody final E entity) {
        service.create(entity);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "createAll", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void createAll(@RequestBody final List<E> entities) {
        for (E entity : entities) {
            service.create(entity);
        }
    }
}
```